# Different validation scores during training when using flow_from_directory vs flow from a h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, h5py

I was testing the usage of an h5 file vs flow_from_directory and noticed different validation scores during training, but very similar scores for training and when tested the model on the test data both of them gives almost the same scores. For the experiment I am using the same model and giving them 5 epochs, and they have both the same starting weights, via get_weights and save_weights. I would like to use the h5 alternative since it cuts down my training time per epoch from 2min to half of a min.

**Using flow from directory**
Here's the scores during training
[image]

And the prediction results on the test data being:

```
loss: 1.9690 - accuracy: 0.4802
```

**Using flow from the h5 file**
[image: Training scores]

And the "trained" model applied to the test data:

```
loss: 1.9695 - accuracy: 0.4822
```

From the stats, looks like it is training from the same data and predicting on the same test data(because of the similar loss and accuracy scores) and the validation data is different.

**How the h5 file was created**
Below I will show the code for inserting the validation data into the dataset. For the training and testing images it's the same code but modifying it accordingly .

```
...
hdf5_file.create_dataset('x_val', val_data_shape, np.uint8)
hdf5_file.create_dataset('y_val', val_label_shape, np.uint8 )
...
for i in range(len(val_it)):
  if i%200 == 0:
    print(f"Validation: Done {i} of {len(val_it)}")
  
  x, y = val_it[i]

  img = x[0]
  label = y[0]
  hdf5_file['x_val'][i, ...] = img
  hdf5_file['y_val'][i, ...] = label
...
```

**How the data was loaded to fetch it into the model**
First I create a datagen that applies the preprocess needed for the Resnet model. For the training data and the test data are done in the same fashion.

```
datagen_val   = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_resnet)
val_it   = datagen_val.flow_from_directory(BASE_PATH + 'val', batch_size=1)


val_x = hdf5_file['x_val']
val_y = hdf5_file['y_val']
datagen_val_h5   = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_resnet)
val_it_h5   = datagen_val_h5.flow((val_x, val_y), batch_size=1)
```

**Question** is, why the loss and accuracy score on the validation dataset differ between the two methods when on training and test they score very similar?

Comment: Do you randomize the split of data used for training and testing? If so, there will be a small variation each time you train (because the training set is slightly different each time). If your model is properly trained (and not over trained), the testing results should be similar.

Comment: No, I don't. They are fixed splits